# Как реализовать бесконечный цикл в потоке?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-mediaplayer

Не получается реализовать бесконечный цикл в потоке, который играет мелодию раз в секунду.

Вот код:

```
MediaPlayer player;
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                f = req(); // запрос
                if(f) loadMusic();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
};

.    .     .    
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
.    .     .

void loadMusic() throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mAssetManager.openFd("1.wav");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
```

> Проблема в том, что через 20 секунд музыка перестаёт играть.

Интересно то, что без потока он работает в среднем 20 минут!

Comment: Погуглите про SoundPool, он какраз используется для воспроизведения коротких звуков

Comment: SoundPool пробовал - не подходит. Длительность мелодии от 5 до 26 секунд. Он примерно через 20 секунд замолкает на полуслове.

Comment: req(); на результат не влияет, т.е. он замолкает несмотря делается что-то кроме MediaPlayer'а или нет.

Comment: Для такой задачи лучше подошёл бы фоновый сервис.